# Chain homotopy and compositions of morphisms.

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Show that if $\alpha_1 \sim \beta_1$ and $\alpha_2 \sim \beta_2$ , then (whenever composition makes sense) $\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2 \sim \beta_1 \circ \beta_2$.

I have two questions.

So are these morphisms ($\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$) maps from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are chain complexes with $$\mathcal{A} := ... \leftarrow A_{n-1} \leftarrow A_n \leftarrow ...$$ and $$\mathcal{C} := ... \leftarrow C_n \leftarrow C_{n+1} \leftarrow ...$$

Or do we have $\alpha_1 : A_1 \rightarrow C_1$, $\alpha_2: A_2 \rightarrow C_2$, $\beta_1: A_1 \rightarrow C_1$, and $\beta_2: A_2 \rightarrow C_2$. I'm assuming its the former, but I'm having problems with both cases.

If its the former, then we have, for every $n$, $\alpha_{1 (n)} : A_n \rightarrow C_n$ and $\alpha_{2(n)}: A_n \rightarrow C_n$. But then how can we compose them? Because for $a \in A_n$, we have $\alpha_{1(n)} \circ \alpha_{2 (n)}(a) = \alpha_{1(n)}(\alpha_{2(n)} (a))$. But $\alpha_{2(n)}(a) \in C_n$, so its not even in the domain of $\alpha_{1(n)}$.

If $\alpha_1: A_n \rightarrow C_n$ and $\alpha_1: A_n \rightarrow C_n$, then $\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2 (a)$ still does not make any sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But are you working with chain homotopies or homotopic maps? See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category_of_chain_complexes

Comment: @Sigur This is the definition in my notes "Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ be chain complexes. Two morphisms $\alpha, \beta : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ are called chain homotopic if there is a sequence of maps $\{ \gamma_n : A_n \rightarrow C_{n+1}\}_{n \in \Bbb{Z}}$ such that for every n, one has the equality $\alpha_n - \beta_n = d^{\mathcal{C}}_{n+1}  \circ \gamma_n + \gamma_{n-1} \circ d^{\mathcal{A}}_n$. So, as I said in the question, I am assuming that it is the first possibility that I said.

Comment: So, IMHO you have three chain complexes.

Comment: @Sigur I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I'm just saying that the compositions $\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2$ and $\beta_1 \circ \beta_2$ do not make sense to me, as I explained above.

Comment: Write $3$ chain complexes: $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ and $\alpha_1,\beta_1: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ and $\alpha_2,\beta_2: \mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2$ are chain complexes maps, in that case since $\alpha_1 \sim \beta_1$ e $\alpha_2 \sim \beta_2$ and so there must be $\mathcal A,\mathcal B,\mathcal C,\mathcal D$ four chain complexes such that $\alpha_1,\beta_1 \colon \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ and $\alpha_2,\beta_2 \colon \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$.

In this way 
$$\alpha_1 =\langle {\alpha_1}_n \colon A_n \to B_n\rangle_{n \in \mathbb Z}$$
$$\alpha_2 =\langle {\alpha_2}_n \colon C_n \to D_n\rangle_{n \in \mathbb Z}$$
$$\beta_1 = \langle {\beta_1}_n \colon A_n \to B_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb Z}$$
$$\beta_2 = \langle {\beta_2}_n \colon C_n \to D_n\rangle_{n \in \mathbb Z}$$

Now in order to be possible that composites $\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2$ and $\beta_1 \circ \beta_2$ exist it must be $\mathcal A= \mathcal D$:
in this way the composite maps are defined as
$${\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2}_{n} = {\alpha_1}_n \circ {\alpha_2}_n \colon C_n \to B_n$$
$${\beta_1 \circ \beta_2}_{n} = {\beta_1}_n \circ {\beta_2}_n \colon C_n \to B_n$$